# Install scrapy on mac error

Tags: python, macos, installation, scrapy, pip

I am new to python. I am trying to install scrapy on mac through the terminal. I am getting the following errors. Let me know what i need to do to install:

```
>>> pip install scrapy
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    pip install scrapy
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Thanks
V

Comment: FYI, in the future indent code blocks with 4 spaces. Welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to do this in an interactive Python session, but it needs to be done in the terminal outside of the Python session.

Also, depending on how your system is set up you'll probably need to use `sudo`, as follows:

```
$ sudo pip install scrapy
```

Answer (score -1):

You should try and install it into a virtual environment, i don't even have to use sudo when installing in one.

Comment: This really doesn't answer the question.

Comment: I agree, it doesn't. But I've been progressing in python and I can thank it to knowing how to use VENV - it allows me to sandbox whatever plugins I want really effectively. I'd recommend to any people getting into Python.